# Error Deploy Railway

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

estuve intentando hacer un deploy de un proyecto realizado con NodeJS, Express y MySQL que estoy haciendo en un curso y me da un error que no entiendo que es. La base de datos se conecta de manera correcta, realizo cambios en ella y los mismos se ven reflejados en Railway, pero no puedo ver el proyecto en la url debido al error que tengo. A continuación les comparto el error...
Desde ya mucha gracias por la ayuda.

```js
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT
at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async ConnectionManager._connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32 {
parent: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:202:17)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
fatal: true
},
original: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:202:17)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
fatal: true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví muchas gracias. Estaban nombradas diferentes las variables de entorno en mi proyecto con respecto a las de Railway. En mi proyecto yo las nombre DB_USER(ejemplo) y en Railway al crear la base de datos de se crean con el nombre MYSQLUSER, y por eso me daba el error. Cambie el nombre de las mismas y funciono correctamente.